# backbone.js events and el

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

Okay, so I've read several other questions regarding Backbone views and events not being fired, however I'm still not getting it sadly.  I been messing with Backbone for about a day, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.  Here's a jsfiddle with what I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/siyegen/e7sNN/3/

```
(function($) {

    var GridView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'grid-view',
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'okay');
        },
        events: {
            'click .grid-view': 'okay'
        },
        okay: function() {
            alert('moo');
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).text('Some Cow');
            return this;
        }
    });

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'),
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'buildGrid');
            this.render();
        },
        events: {
            'click button#buildGrid': 'buildGrid'
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).append($('<div>').addClass('gridApp'));
            $(this.el).append('<button id="buildGrid">Build</button>');
        },
        buildGrid: function() {
            var gridView = new GridView();
            this.$('.gridApp').html(gridView.render().el);
        }

    });

    var appView = new AppView();

})(jQuery);
```

The `okay` event on the GridView does not fire, I'm assuming because `div.grid-view` does not exist when the event is first bound.  How should I handle the binding and firing of an event that's built on a view dynamically?  (Also, it's a short example, but feel free to yell at me if I'm doing anything else that I shouldn't)

Comment: because `el` is div tag with `.grid-view` . and you are finding `.grid-view` class name element in that div . which you won't get it .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is that the events on GridView:

```
events: {
    'click .grid-view': 'okay'
}
```

say:

> when you click on a **descendent** that matches `'.grid-view'`, call `okay`

The events are bound with this [snippet from `backbone.js`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L1069):

```
if (selector === '') {
  this.$el.on(eventName, method);
} else {
  this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
}
```

So the `.grid-view` element has to be contained within your GridView's `this.el` and your `this.el` is `<div class="grid-view">`. If you change your `events` to this:

```
events: {
    'click': 'okay'
}
```

you'll hear your cows (or "hear them in your mind" after reading the alert depending on how crazy this problem has made you).

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5dhDW/

Comment: That worked, thanks.  In general, if I want to bind an event to the element the view itself is creating, I'd leave out the selector?  I tested that and it works with another view, just making sure that's the right way to go about things.

Comment: @siyegen: Right. Have a look at the first branch of the `backbone.js` snippet I included; if there is no selector, then the event is bound directly to `this.el` using `$(this.el).bind(eventName, method);`, if there is a selector then the event is bound with `delegate`.

Comment: but what when I want to fire event only when `this.el` has `grid-view` class ?

Comment: @Jashwant: You'd probably have to check `this.$el.hasClass('grid-view')` inside the click handler or manually add and remove a raw click handler as needed without going through `events`.

Comment: @muistooshort, Okay so there's no direct way.