# Triggering an event on el in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, dom-events, backbone-events

I have a view that creates and populates a Selectlist.  I want to bind an event on the Change event (When the user selects a different Option.

It simply outputs something close to this:

```
<select>
   <option value="id">ID Name</option
</select>
```

---

The View:

```
App.Views.SessionList = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName: 'select',
   id: 'sessionList',
   events: {
       'change': 'selectionChanged'
   },
   initialize: function () {
       // Load Collection
       _.bindAll(this, 'selectionChanged');

       this.template = _.template($('#optionsTemplate').html());
       this.Sessiontemplate = _.template($('#session_template').html());
       this.SelectedSessiontemplate = _.template($('#selected_session_template').html());

       // Create Collection
       this.SessionList = new App.Collections.SessionList();

       // Set Bindings
       this.SessionList.bind('add', this.addSession, this);
       this.SessionList.bind('reset', this.addSessions, this);


       this.render();

       this.SessionList.fetch();
   },
   render: function () {

       return this;
   },
   addSession: function (item, num) {
       if (num === 0) {
           $(this.el).append(this.SelectedSessiontemplate(item.toJSON()));
           console.log("Selected");
       }
       else {
           $(this.el).append(this.Sessiontemplate(item.toJSON()));
       }
   },
   addSessions: function () {
       var self = this;
       // Add all Rows
       for (var i = 0; i < self.SessionList.models.length; i++) {
           this.addSession(self.SessionList.models[i], i);
       }
   },
   selectionChanged: function (e) {
       var field = $(e.currentTarget);
       var value = $("option:selected", field).val();
   }
});
```

The Session Template is just simply:

```
<option value="{{Id}}">{{Name}}</option>
```

The event never gets triggered, and It seems that it isn't getting binded correctly. I want to trigger it on the change of the select list.

I originally thought I may be having an issue similar to:
[backbone.js events and el](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542756/backbone-js-events-and-el-question), however it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to debug your problem directly, because we don't have all of the information (what does `SessionList` look like... the templates, etc).

BUT, I have paired down your example to some code where the event does, indeed work.  Hopefully, you can build it up from there?  You can [fork the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianGenisio/dZzsJ/1/) if you want to get to a place where it fails for you and we can try to help further.

```
window.App = { Views: {} };

App.Views.SessionList = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'select',

    events: {
        'change': 'selectionChanged'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'selectionChanged');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).append('<option value="foo">Option 1</option>');
        $(this.el).append('<option value="bar">Option 2</option>');                
        return this;
    },

    selectionChanged: function (e) {
        var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        console.log("SELECTED", value);
    }
});

var view = new App.Views.SessionList();
$("body").append(view.el);
```

Given that code, you will get a console log with the value every time you select an item.

Since you aren't getting that, I am guessing you are seeing an exception or something like that?  Does your debugger give you any hints?

Good luck!

Comment: Silly, but Chrome was caching the page and updates weren't being shown even after many tries.  But, I did use your fiddle, which allowed me to build up and fix some things.  Thank you!